# How to make ashx load custom XML on iis start up?

Tags: c#, iis-8

I want to make my .ashx capable of reading configurations(query info , settings ...etc) in custom xml files into a static variable as soon as IIS start.

We currently put every thing inside web.config(in appSettings) and it became a mess.
So I hope to reduce the mess in web.config by moving custom configurations
to some custom configuration file.

I have thought of using static constructor of c# but it doesn't seen to be the thing I am looking for because it seems to run before iis starts(on clr start?)...

Comment: It is more common today to use JSON format (like ASP.NET Core does), so maybe you should not use XML any more.

Comment: @LexLi the problem is actually about loading or setting static variables on IIS start.